# Is clearing the token from local storage enough? to create an effect of a session timeout due to inactivity?

Tags: angularjs, session, oauth, oauth-2.0, session-timeout

I am building an angularjs/web-api application. It uses OAuth token based authentication. I have a requirement to implement a session timeout based on inactivity. I am using ng-idle for the client side to implement the effect.

My question is:
1. Is it enough for me to clear the token from local-storage(i am storing the token here for persistence) ?

I observed the above approach to create a need for a new login. However I am afraid if I should handle the situation in my application's counterpart - the web-api?. And if so, how do i do it?

How do i enforce or manually expire my oauth token upon inactivity?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

`Token` solutions works with tokens that expires in some **orig_iat** + **X** time... you can store that `timestamp` into your token, and code your server to accept only `valid` tokens. I would suggest you to clear the token, which you have stored in `localStorage/sessionStorage` and also look ng-idle plugin.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-idle

You can set your configuration here and handle the clearing of `localStorage/sessionStorage` in your `run` function.

```
myApp.config(['KeepaliveProvider', 'IdleProvider', function(KeepaliveProvider, IdleProvider) {
  IdleProvider.idle(5);
  IdleProvider.timeout(5);
  KeepaliveProvider.interval(10);
}]);
```

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens

1. iat Issued At - When the token was issued (unix timestamp)
2. exp Expiry - The token expiry date (unix timestamp)
3. nbf Not Before - The earliest point in time that the token can be
   used (unix timestamp)

Comment: Hello, Let me re-iterate my question. I already am using the ng-idle module so my client side requirement for timeout is taken care.

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally pressed the enter button. All i need now is to figure out a way to 'manually expire' the token from the server side.. I am not sure if this is required or is it do-able etc.. but i am looking for some insight. If there is a way how do i do it.? Please note. i am already cleaning up the token i stored in the localstorage.. But my quest is is that enough or should i do it in the server side also.? TIA.

Comment: @user6916098: A token generated will have an issued time and expiry time, you don't need to do anything from front-end apart from clearing the token... your server side will not authenticate the old token you send comparing it with the expiry time period...